# Calling Mobile Menu Function on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in JS that I'm calling on window resize. In a mobile tablet use case changing the orientation from landscape to portrait and vice-versa changes the window dimensions. Not only that but it is helpful in testing in browsers for desktop.

So the function shouldn't just be applied on document load but the window resize. Currently, window resize reloading doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions would be helpful.

You can see the example here:

```
// Mobile Menu Function
function mobMenu() {
 var $window = $(window);
 var $html = $('html');
 var $dropdown = $('.dropdown-nav > a');
 var $allDropdown = $('.dropdown-nav');
 var $hamburger = $('.hamburger > a');
 var $hamburgerInPage = $('.hamburger-in-page > a');
 var $menu = $('.cpi-main-nav');
 var $menuInPage = $('.in-page-nav nav');
 var $isiOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i) != null;

  if ($isiOS) {
      $(document).on('click touchend', function () {
        $dropdown.parent().removeClass('active-hit');
      });
      $dropdown.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      });
      $html.addClass('mobile-view');
  } else {
      $html.removeClass('mobile-view');
  }

  if ($window.width() < 900) {

    $hamburger.on('click', function(e){
      $menu.toggleClass('open-close-nav');
    });

    $hamburgerInPage.on('click', function(e){
      $menuInPage.toggleClass('open-close-in-page-nav');
    });

    // On Click Drop Down
    $dropdown.on('click', function(e){
      // Close Everything but the current Drop Down
      $allDropdown.not($(this).parent()).removeClass('active-hit');

      //if current is open then close
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active-hit')) {
          $(this).parent().removeClass('active-hit');
        }
      //if current is closed then open
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active-hit')) {
          $(this).parent().addClass('active-hit');
        }

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $html.addClass('mobile-view');

  } else {
    $html.removeClass('mobile-view');
    $menu.removeClass('open-close-nav');
    $dropdown.parent().removeClass('active-hit');
  }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
  mobMenu();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  mobMenu();
});
```

Comment: some devices (browsers) don't trigger `resize` on orientation change, you need to add `window.addEventListener("orientationchange", mobMenu);` too. By the way, no need to have anonymous functions here, you can just do `$(window).resize(mobMenu);`

Comment: Thanks but any insight into why window.resize isn't working on desktop sometimes?

Comment: same thing, unless it comes from an error in the code (which doesn't seem to). Browsers implement the event differently, for example, some will fire it repeatedly during resize, some only at the end of resizing, etc

Comment: Ok thanks seem to be working now in chrome. Do you want to write a reply so I can accept the answer?

Comment: Actually it isn't working in Chrome. Odd

Comment: do you mean the function is not triggered on orientation change, or not triggered at all?

Comment: When I resize the browser window I can't click into the menu - the class "open-close-nav" basically isn't applied. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: You can see the example here: https://einstein.uk-cpi.com

Comment: can u please write what exactly you want to achieve ? i got a bit lost there

Comment: The whole logic is rather bogus to begin with ... you keep on piling on event handlers here with every new call to `mobMenu`. IMHO it makes little sense to assign such event handlers depending on window width to begin with. Assign a proper click handler to the menu button, _once_, and outside any conditions or additional checks. Since you are going to _hide_ that button in situations where it is not appropriate, there is no danger that any user would _click_ it in this situation either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe said, you are piling event handlers, You have all your code inside the `mobMenu` function, and that is executed every-time the window is resized. So when you resize the first time it works, second time it doesn't, third time miraculously it works again :O.

**This is your present situation:**

```
// This function is called when page loads/window resizes
function mobMenu() {
    // Show hide Dropdown Menu button depending on window size when page loads/window resizes
    if ($window.width() < 900){
        $html.addClass('mobile-view');
    }
    // Register a new click event-handler when window loads/resize [MISTAKE!!!]
    $hamburger.on('click', function (e) {
        $menu.toggleClass('open-close-nav');
    });
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    mobMenu();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    mobMenu();
});
```

**This is how you deal with it:**

```
// This function is called when page loads only
function setupMobMenu() {
    // Declare variables
    $html = $('.selector');
    // Put all window adjusting code in a function
    function adjustMyPageToWindow(){
        // Show/Hide Dropdown Menu button depending on window size
        if ($window.width() < 900){
            $html.addClass('mobile-view');
        }
    }
    // Register a new click event-handler when window loads only
    $hamburger.on('click', function (e) {
        $menu.toggleClass('open-close-nav');
    });
    // Register all other event-handlers here
    //.....
    // Register window resize event-handler
    $(window).resize(adjustMyPageToWindow);
    // Adjust page now (On page load)
    adjustMyPageToWindow();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setupMobMenu();
});
```

**Working Code:**

```
function setupMobMenu() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $html = $('html');
    var $dropdown = $('.dropdown-nav > a');
    var $allDropdown = $('.dropdown-nav');
    var $hamburger = $('.hamburger > a');
    var $hamburgerInPage = $('.hamburger-in-page > a');
    var $menu = $('.cpi-main-nav');
    var $menuInPage = $('.in-page-nav nav');
    var $isiOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i) != null;

    if ($isiOS) {
        $(document).on('click touchend', function () {
            $dropdown.parent().removeClass('active-hit');
        });
        $dropdown.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $html.addClass('mobile-view');
    } else {
        $html.removeClass('mobile-view');
    }

    function adjustMyPageToWindow(){
        $(window).resize(function () {
            if ($window.width() < 900) {
                $html.addClass('mobile-view');
            } else {
                $html.removeClass('mobile-view');
                $menu.removeClass('open-close-nav');
                $dropdown.parent().removeClass('active-hit');
            }
        });
    }

    $hamburger.on('click', function (e) {
        $menu.toggleClass('open-close-nav');
    });

    $hamburgerInPage.on('click', function (e) {
        $menuInPage.toggleClass('open-close-in-page-nav');
    });

    // On Click Drop Down
    $dropdown.on('click', function (e) {
        // Close Everything but the current Drop Down
        $allDropdown.not($(this).parent()).removeClass('active-hit');

        //if current is open then close
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active-hit')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active-hit');
        }
        //if current is closed then open
        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active-hit')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active-hit');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Register window resize event-handler
    $(window).resize(adjustMyPageToWindow);
    // Adjust page now (On page load)
    adjustMyPageToWindow();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setupMobMenu();
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is what was required!